# NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities. QueryImpl.throwNoResultException

Tags: jpa

We have a java web application deployed into payara 164 application Server.
Host machine is a debian 9.3 server, used database is a mariadb-server-10.1, java version is "1.8.0_131".

Recently we are facing some problems among which the one below. It is just an instance since it happens randomly with a lot of other Objects even though indeed they are not NULL but correctly populated.

> javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException at **dmlm.models.entities.User.getCustomer(User.java:337)**
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.

EDIT:

in several place is called the following method:

```
public Customer getCustomerByUser(User user)
{
    TypedQuery<Customer> q = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByUser", Customer.class);
    q.setParameter("userId", user.getId());
    if (LOG.isLoggable(Level.FINER)) {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="per stampare nei log una query runtime">
        org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session session
                = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).getActiveSession();
        DatabaseQuery databaseQuery = ((EJBQueryImpl) q).getDatabaseQuery();
        databaseQuery.prepareCall(session, new DatabaseRecord());
        DatabaseRecord recordWithValues = new DatabaseRecord();
        recordWithValues.add(new DatabaseField("userId"), user.getId());

        String sqlStringWithArgs
                = databaseQuery.getTranslatedSQLString(session, recordWithValues);
        LOG.finest(sqlStringWithArgs);
        //</editor-fold>
    }
    return q.getSingleResult();
}
```

the log part is just to print out the real query created with parameter

the named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByUser",
            query = "SELECT m FROM Customer m JOIN m.users us WHERE m.deleted = false AND us.id = :userId")
```

As said, the result should be a single result with customer id

EDIT 2:
We have tried to change the db from maria-db to mysql, with no success

Comment: Where's the CODE that creates and executes the query? Where's the debugging, referring to the JPA providers log?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `getSingleResult()` only in case you are 100% sure that particular record exist in database (**uniquely**). The thrown exception is runtime. Runtime exception = programmer issue.

If you do not know if record uniquely exists you can use this construct.

```
public Entity getEntityByName(String name) {
    TypedQuery<Entity> query = em.createNamedQuery(Entity.GET_ENTITY_BY_NAME, Entity.class);
    query.setParameter(Entity.PRM_NAME, name);
    List<Project> found = query.getResultList();

    if (found.isEmpty()) {
        return null; //or throw checked exception data not found
    } else {
        return found.get(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, I'd venture to say you should use `getSingleResult()` for single-result aggregate queries *exclusively*. Single result is neither 'single or no' result nor 'single or more' result.

Comment: the problem is that result query should be populated with a single result. Some times, the record that normally return correctly the single result, return a null result (that is impossible)

Comment: Does anybody have any idea?